# Cypher: COLLECT and return min / max of the groups

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking to get a min / max value as return from a query from nodes/relations that have a UUID. I want to gather all UUID's as groups and find for each group of UUIDs the min / max.

I tried

```
match (u:User) -[r:relation ]-> (n:Node) 
return (COLLECT (r.uuid)), max(n.value),  min(n.value)
```

I receive all UUID's in a list and from all UUID's the min and max instead per grouped UUID. How could I change my query to get the desired selection?

Example:

```
UUID  Value
1      1
1      5
1      7 
2      3
2      6
```

> Result: 1,2 1/7 **instead of** 1 1/7 - 2 3/6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to leave the first column uncollected:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r:relation]->(n:Node)
RETURN r.uuid, MAX(n.value), MIN(n.value)
```

Comment: Wow, sometimes the solution is easier than the thoughts you've made... :) Thanks a lot! This works as expected.